# NetBeans Post Build Script

Tags: java, netbeans, build, scripting

I'm using NetBeans 6.8, and I want to run a script to construct an SQLite database with a predefined schema after each build. I don't see any options under Build Configuration. Is this feature not yet supported?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out. Just edited the build.xml file that associates itself with the project. Details on how to do it are self-contained.

```
<target name="-post-compile">   
    <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
          <arg line="/c DatabaseInitializer.bat"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Hmm. What about Maven. Don't you happen to have any idea?